# What Python tool support automation of Sciter based desktop application

Tags: automated-testing, python, uiautomation, desktop-application

I have been using pywinauto for automation of desktop application. This tool was fine until we started using Sciter (see https://sciter.com for more info) on some screens. Pywinauto supports Win32 API, MS UI interfaces but Sciter is HTML based UI framework, so they are not compatible.

I found the next info here https://sciter.com/forums/topic/how-to-automate-sciter-ui-is-it-supports-to-seleniumqtp-for-automation/

```
Sciter exposes UI Automation interfaces and IAccessible (/engine/win/win-accessible.h) so tools that know about them can be used
```

Can some one suggest any Python tool for automation of Sciter based desktop application? if not - any not Python tool?

Regards,
Sergey

Comment: "UI Automation interfaces" and "MS UI interfaces" is the same API. If Sciter uses it, you have to use `Application(backend="uia")` from pywinauto. Are you using it? More details about backends are in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pywinauto is capable to do that.

"UI Automation interfaces" and "MS UI interfaces" is the same API. If Sciter uses it, you have to use `Application(backend="uia")` from pywinauto. More details about backends are in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).